# How to create a datetime column in pandas based on two columns date and time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Lets say I have following `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03"], "Time":[0,1,10]})
```

I want another column which is a `datetime` using the Date and the Time Columns.

### Expected result

```
         Date  Time            DateTime
0  2022-01-01     0 2022-01-01 00:00:00
1  2022-01-02     1 2022-01-02 01:00:00
2  2022-01-03    10 2022-01-03 10:00:00
```

### Trial

I tried this failed solution:

```
df["DateTime"] = str(df["Date"]) + " " + str(df["Time"]) + ":00"
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> df
         Date  Time                                           DateTime
0  2022-01-01     0  0    2022-01-01\n1    2022-01-02\n2    2022-01...
1  2022-01-02     1  0    2022-01-01\n1    2022-01-02\n2    2022-01...
2  2022-01-03    10  0    2022-01-01\n1    2022-01-02\n2    2022-01...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `Date` and `Time` add with `to_datetime` and `to_timedelta`

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'],unit='hour')
df
Out[388]: 
         Date  Time                 new
0  2022-01-01     0 2022-01-01 00:00:00
1  2022-01-02     1 2022-01-02 01:00:00
2  2022-01-03    10 2022-01-03 10:00:00
```

Comment: How to do this if I have date as 'DD.MM.YYY' and time as 'HH:MM:SS', both are just objects?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be the following:

```
df["DateTime"] = df["Date"].astype(str) + " " + df["Time"].astype(str) + ":00"
```

Then convert to `datetime`:

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"])
```

Hence the output is as expected:

```
>>> df
         Date  Time            DateTime
0  2022-01-01     0 2022-01-01 00:00:00
1  2022-01-02     1 2022-01-02 01:00:00
2  2022-01-03    10 2022-01-03 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['date'] = [d.date() for d in df['datetime']]
df['time'] = [d.time() for d in df['datetime']]
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```